# Form element title is not displaying translation

Tags: forms, i18n-l10n

I have got my own module providing a form and there is one element called "Estimated time" defined like this:

```
$form['informacie_o_incidente']['field_incident_doba'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Estimated time'),
  '#markup' => '<div class="control-group form-item"><label class="control-label">Estimated time:</label><div id="field_incident_doba_wrapper" class="controls">'.$doba.'</div></div>',
);
```

I have translated the text "Estimated field" via translation interface, cleared cache several times (both GUI and with drush cc all command). However, when I run this drush command:

```
drush ev "print t('Estimated time');"
```

I am getting correctly translated string. So why not on the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need  add `t()` in `#markup` and translate the string `'Estimated time:'`

```
$form['informacie_o_incidente']['field_incident_doba'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Estimated time'),
  '#markup' => '<div class="control-group form-item"><label class="control-label">'.t('Estimated time:').'</label><div id="field_incident_doba_wrapper" class="controls">'.$doba.'</div></div>',
);
```